# What would the magento 2 equivalent of Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail(); be?

Tags: model, magento2

What is the equivalent of this code in magento 2?

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId('1');
$customer->loadByEmail('test@gmail.com'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
protected $customerCollection;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerCollection,
    ...     
)
{
    ...
    $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
    ...
}
```

use below code in your function:-

```
$customerObj = $this->customerCollection;
$customerObj->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customerObj->loadByEmail('test@gmail.com');
```